# Declaring stdout as stder

Tags: redirect

```
$ cat x
cat: x: No such file or directory
$ cat y
This is y.
$ cat x y 1> hold 2>&1
cat: x: No such file or directory
This is y.
```

Why stder got redirected to hold as well? stder got declared as stdout **after** redirecting stdout into hold and there is no more redirect after declaring happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

- Redirections are read sequentially left-to-right
- after redirections are read, file descriptors no longer point to what they were before.

#### Answer

The core reason why is because `1` no longer refers to stdout when `2>&1` is read, but to `hold` file, since redirections are processed left to right.

First of all, remember that all commands within Unix environment have standard streams, which are referenced via file descriptors 0 for stdin, 1 for stdout, and 2 for stderr. There are of course rare [exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22367920/3701431), but 99% of times this is the standard file descriptors.

Redirections such as `m>n`, `m>&1` and `m<n` perform [syscall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) [`dup2()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) which makes copies of [file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) ( aka file handles). In `m>n`, `m` is typically a file descriptor, and `n` can be either a file or another file descriptor. That's exactly what `2>&1` are - integer references to file descriptors corresponding to stdin and stdout.

When `cat x y 1> hold 2>&1` occurs, shell first will  open `hold` file, and reference it via next available file descriptor, typically `3`, and then perform copy of that file descriptor via `dup2(3,1)`. `dup2()` syscall is kinda like `cp` command, where you have `cp old copy`. Thus, now file descriptor `1` refers to the same [open file description](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195164/85039) (aka `struct file` in Linux kernel) independently of the other file descriptor 3.

When `2>&1` is seen, shell performs second `dup2(1,2)`. So now file descriptor 2 is an independent copy of file descriptor 1, but what was it before `2>&1` was seen ? `1` was already pointing to the open file `hold`. From there shell will perform `fork` and `execve` syscall to actually run `cat` as subprocess, which will inherit open file descriptors.

But as far as commands are concerned, in this case `cat`, it writes to file descriptors 1 and 2 without being aware they are copies of something else.

You can see all of that in action with `strace` command:

```
# ... is several irrelevant lines skipped of bash opening libraries 
$ strace -f -edup2,openat,write bash -c 'cat testFile.txt > hold 2>&1'
...
strace: Process 17766 attached
[pid 17766] openat(AT_FDCWD, "hold", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
[pid 17766] dup2(3, 1)                  = 1
[pid 17766] dup2(1, 2)                  = 2
[pid 17766] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 17766] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 17766] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
[pid 17766] openat(AT_FDCWD, "testFile.txt", O_RDONLY) = 3
[pid 17766] write(1, "potato\n\nNAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE"..., 248) = 248
[pid 17766] +++ exited with 0 +++
```

#### Side note:

If the original intention is to let `stderr` show up on screen, then `2>&1` can be removed from the command. `cat x y > hold` is sufficient to send stdout to `hold` file and stderr to screen.

If the intend is to send `stderr` via `stdin` to a pipe, we will need to swap file descriptors

```
$ cat x y 3>&2 2>&1 2>&3 2>hold | grep --color=always file
this is a test file y
$ cat hold
cat: x: No such file or directory
```

This basically performs a swap like so:

```
# 3>&2 open new fd 3 , save copy of fd 2 there
dup2(2, 3)                              = 3
# 2>&1 , now turn 2 into copy of 1; 2 is still safe as fd 3
dup2(1, 2)                              = 2
# 2>&3 Now let's make 2 refer to what originally was 1, but now saved in 3
dup2(3, 2)                              = 2
# open file "hold" , which will be next available integer fd
openat(AT_FDCWD, "hold", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
# 2>hold
dup2(4, 2)                              = 2
```